# Asp.Net Nuget List-Package Error

Tags: nuget

I don't know where is my mistake. I tried to execute "List-Package" in Package manager console and getting following error in Nuget package.

PM> list-package
The term 'list-package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:13
+ list-package <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (list-package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

NuGet does not have a List-Package command. You are probably looking for the **Get-Package** command.

The [list of commands for NuGet's Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) is available from NuGet's web site.